# Multi-node Kubernetes cluster in docker for Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes

Is it possible to have a Kubernetes multi-node cluster in a docker container?
I read about Minikube and Kind but they allow to run Kubernetes only on local computers.

Comment: What sort of solution are you looking for?  I know Kind will run multiple Kubernetes nodes in separate containers, but yes, usually all on the same host; if you want a multi-host Kubernetes setup, you usually dedicate the systems to Kubernetes (and don't try to run Kubernetes in Docker on a dedicated node, skip the Docker layer) and use a more robust installation tool like kops or kubeadm.  "How do I install a Kubernetes cluster" isn't a programming-related question and isn't on-topic for Stack Overflow, though, beyond the very developer-oriented tools you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's possible. You can have a look at below tutorials:

1. [Docker multinode](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/)
2. [Tutorial: Spin up Your Kubernetes-in-Docker Cluster and They Will Come](https://www.conjur.org/blog/tutorial-spin-up-your-kubernetes-in-docker-cluster-and-they-will-come/)
3. [Multi-node Kubernetes with KDC: A quick and dirty guide](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/multi-kubernetes-kdc-quick-and-dirty-guide/)